# Why I am not able to invoke 'explicit a (string x)'?

Tags: c++, casting, constructor, explicit

I am not able to Invoke 'explicit a (string x)' using the object a3, I got two compilation errors such as:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
>
> [Error]   initializing argument 1 of 'a::a(int)' [-fpermissive]

My expected out put is 'int int double string';

Could somebody help me to remove these errors? Thanks for your valuble time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std; 


struct a{

    a(int x=0){cout<<" int ";
    }
    inline a (double x){cout<<" double ";
    }
    explicit a (string x){ cout<<" string ";
    }

};


int main()
{
    a a0(NULL);
    a a1=9;
    a a2=1.1;
    a a3=("Widf"); //Error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit constructor has to be called via the structure/class name:

```
a("Widf")
```

Using an equality as a constructor is not an explicit constructor call.
You can use this:

```
a a3 = a("Widf")
```

Which will:

1. Create a temporary object a
2. Use a copy constructor to create a3

the compiler optimizer should be able to optimize this though.

Alternatively, you can just write

```
a a3("Widf")
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically, C++ interprets

```
a a3 = ("Widf");
```

As "evaluate the expression `"Widf"`, then construct an object of type `a` called `a3` that is initialized to be equal to it."  Since `"Widf"` has type `const char[4]`, C++ will only be able to initialize `a3` to `"Widf"` if there is an implicit conversion constructor available.  Since you've explicitly marked the constructor `explicit`, this implicit conversion isn't available, hence the error.

To fix this, try rewriting the line as

```
a a3("Widf");
```

This doesn't try to evaluate `"Widf"` first, but instead directly passes it as a parameter to the constructor.

Hope this helps!